# PHP: What should be the permission for the directory where I store user uploaded files?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

- I'm using Linux hosting, & storing some user-uploaded files. What will be the permission (i.e. 0755) for the **directory** where I'll keep these uploaded files?
- Also, what should be the new permission of the uploaded **file**? Currently I'm giving 0755 permission using the `chmod` command, is it secure enough?

Now I'm using code something like:

```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
        // CHMOD
        chmod($targetPath, 0755);
    } else {
        return array(false,"Can not move file. Upload failed.");
    }
```

where `$targetPath` is the new location of the uploaded file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 0750, owned by the webserver process (www-data?). There's no reason to grant anyone BUT the webserver any kind of rights on that directory, unless you have another account that requires it. In which case, create a dedicated group for your www-data and "other" accounts, and chgrp the directory to that new group and make it 0770.

Unless you have very good reason, do NOT grant execute rights on the upload file. If you're not VERY careful handling the upload, someone can send up and a binary and your server will open the door wide. So...0640 on files, 0750 on directories.

Comment: Thanks. That was really explanatory.

Comment: If I set 0640 or 0750 how will anywone able view the file? I mean, when some user requests an uploaded resource (suppose, image) then shouldn't he be able to perform read request?

Comment: remember, it's the webserver accessing the file, not the remote user.